# AMPScript to retrieve TODAY created rows on an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have this piece AMPScript to send an email that retrieves all the new records that have submitted a form in a MC Microsite today:

```
%%[
VAR @currentSystemTime, @Today
SET @currentSystemTime = NOW()
SET @Today= FormatDate(SystemDateToLocalDate(@currentSystemTime), "YYYY-MM-DD")
]%%
Here is the list of the people requesting more information today (%%=v(@Today)=%%):
<br>
<br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
</tr>
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @i
set @rows = LookupRows("TestDE","SubmissionDate",@Today)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
var @EmailAddress
set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @EmailAddress = field(@row,"EmailAddress")
]%%
<tr>
<td>%%=v(@EmailAddress)=%%</td>
</tr>
%%[
next @i ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
No rows found
%%[ endif ]%%
</table>
```

However, we've found that only those records whose timestamp i.e Wednesday, 14 of Septembre, 12:00AM are retrieved to be pulled out on an email. The field type is set to Date and unless we capture the data without the time, the records won't be pulled out.(Only those that have time= 12AM).

Is there any function to pull out records that were captured on a DE since the new day started?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to set up a Query to put this into a separate DE. You can do something simple like just the past 24 hours, or go more complex and do between two specific times (e.g. 12:00AM and 11:59PM)

You would then just pull this entire DE inside the email via your lookup.  My recommendation would be to add a 'secret' field with a default of '1' to allow for easy lookup via ampscript.

You can then automate this and the email send inside automation studio and set the data extension to overwrite on each import.