# Using date time of today in look up ordered rows -Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

Im trying to use a lookupordered row expression to find rows that have a submission date of today and display them, unfortunately I am not finding any matches. I am unsure if my syntax is incorrect or my understanding of date time is incorrect.

```
%%[
VAR @currentSystemTime, @Today SET @currentSystemTime = NOW()
SET @Today= FormatDate(SystemDateToLocalDate(@currentSystemTime), "YYYY-MM-DD")
]%%

%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i
set @numRowsToReturn = 20 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("New-OPT_in_response-TODAY",@numRowsToReturn,"Clinician_Email desc, SubmissionDate asc","SubmissionDate", @today)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @Clinemail, @date
    set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @clinemail = field(@row,"Clinician_Email")
    set @subdate = field(@row,"SubmissionDate")

    ]%%

    Row %%=v(@i)=%%, Clinician Email is %%=v(@clinemail)=%%, the time was %%=v(@subdate)=%%

    %%[ 
  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying the @today variable and seeing if it matches the format of Submission Date?

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution here -
[AMPScript to retrieve TODAY created rows on an email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140616/ampscript-to-retrieve-today-created-rows-on-an-email?rq=1)

It appears the issue is related to date time being the full value and not in the format expected, I ran a query using date time then stamped a lookup value in the DE, this works.